# Spring MVC. Not recognizing RequestMapping annotation name attribute when loading context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have an application with one Spring `@Controller` annotated with `@RequestMapping`.
Using Spring (core and webmvc) 4.1.0.RELEASE or higher I'm getting exception when starting the app server.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.name()Ljava/lang/String;
at method RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMapping annotation, RequestCondition<?> customCondition)
```

Debugging, using Eclipse inspect, the method variable `annotation` does not contains `name` attribute and fails at action `annotation.name()`. All the other attributes values are correct (they have the values defined in the Controller method annotated with `@RequestMapping`).

I'm using Tomcat 7 and Maven 2.3.
`mvn dependency:tree` does not shows other Spring version than 4.1.0.RELEASE.
The error does not occurs when using Spring 4.0.7.RELEASE or lower.
Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: based on the message for some reason it things name is a method. can you please show us the config

Comment: Re-check that all your libs are the same version. `RequestMapping` is in `spring-web` while `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is in `spring-webmvc`. The `name()` method was added in 4.1.0.RELEASE I believe.

Comment: spring-web and spring-webmvc have the same version. The source code in <b>RequestMapping</b> shows the <b>name</b> attribute, but when inspecting it using Eclipse inspect tool it does not.

Comment: `@Controller
public final class MessageController { ... @RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.MESSAGE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody MessageResponse storeMessage(@RequestBody MessageRequest msg) {
  log(msg);
  messageDAO.save(msg);
  MessageResponse response = buildResponse(msg);
  return response;
 }`

Comment: Seems like a classpath issue. An old version of RequestMapping was being loaded. Closing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a classpath issue. An old version of RequestMapping was being loaded.