# Java SpringMVC autowired BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am using Spring MVC on Tomcat. When I try to start tomcat I get this exception:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.path()[Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5200)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.path()[Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.matches(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector$1.doWith(HandlerMethodSelector.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(HandlerMethodSelector.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 25 more
```

SRC:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);
    private final TaskStorage storage;

    @Autowired
    public IndexController(TaskStorage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("tasks", storage.getAllTasks());

        return "index";
    }
...
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TaskStorage {

    public TaskStorage() {

    }

    public void gitCreateBranch(String key, String branchName) {
        ServiceManager.get().git.createBranch(branchName);
    }
...
```

Service manager:

```
public class ServiceManager {

    private static volatile ServiceManager instance;

    public final JiraService jira;
    public final GitService git;
    public final JenkinsService jenkins;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConfiguration conf;

    private ServiceManager() {
        this.jira = new JiraServiceSynchronousImpl(conf);
        this.git = new JGitGitServiceImpl(conf);
        this.jenkins = new SimpleJenkinsServiceImpl(conf);
    }

    public static ServiceManager get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ServiceManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ServiceManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Service configuration:

```
package com.etnetera.dev.storage;

@Component
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    public final JiraConfiguration jira;
    public final GitConfiguration git;
    public final JenkinsConfiguration jenkins;
    public final JnpConfiguration jnp;

    public ServiceConfiguration() {
        this(null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Autowired
    public ServiceConfiguration(JiraConfiguration jira, GitConfiguration git,
            JenkinsConfiguration jenkins, JnpConfiguration jnp) {
        super();
        this.jira = jira;
        this.git = git;
        this.jenkins = jenkins;
        this.jnp = jnp;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Component
    public static class JenkinsConfiguration {
        public final String url;
        public final String defaultJobName;
        public final String defaultJobNameParam;
        public final String userName;
        public final String password;

        public JenkinsConfiguration() {
            this(null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        @Autowired
        public JenkinsConfiguration(
                @Value("${jenkins.url}") String url,
                @Value("${jenkins.defaultJobName}") String defaultJobName,
                @Value("${jenkins.defaultJobNameParam}") String defaultJobNameParam,
                @Value("${jenkins.userName}") String userName,
                @Value("${jenkins.password}") String password) {
            super();
            this.url = url;
            this.defaultJobName = defaultJobName;
            this.defaultJobNameParam = defaultJobNameParam;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getJobUrl(String jobName) {
            return getJobUrl(jobName, null);
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class GitConfiguration {
        public final Git git;
        public final String localRepoPath;

        public GitConfiguration() throws IOException {
            this(null);
        }

        @Autowired
        public GitConfiguration(
                @Value("${git.localRepoPath}") String localRepoPath)
                throws IOException {
            this.git = new Git(new FileRepository(localRepoPath + "/.git"));
            this.localRepoPath = localRepoPath;
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class JiraConfiguration {
        public final JiraRestClient client;
        public final SearchRestClient searchClient;
        public final IssueRestClient issueClient;
        public final String jiraUser;

        public JiraConfiguration() throws URISyntaxException {
            this(null, null, null);
        }

        @Autowired
        public JiraConfiguration(@Value("${jira.userName}") String userName,
                @Value("${jira.pass}") String pass,
                @Value("${jira.url}") String url) throws URISyntaxException {
            this.jiraUser = userName;

            JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
            URI uri = new URI(url);
            this.client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri,
                    userName, pass);
            this.searchClient = client.getSearchClient();
            this.issueClient = client.getIssueClient();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class JnpConfiguration {
        public final Map<String, String> serviceUrls;
        public final String defaultServiceUrl;
        public final String defaultProjectName;

        public JnpConfiguration() {
            this(null, null);
        }

        @Autowired
        public JnpConfiguration(
                @Value("${jnp.defaultServer}") String defaultServiceUrl,
                @Value("${jnp.defaultProjectName}") String defaultProjectName) {
            super();
            this.serviceUrls = null;
            this.defaultServiceUrl = defaultServiceUrl;
            this.defaultProjectName = defaultProjectName;
        }
    }
}
```

Web config:

```
package com.etnetera.dev.config;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.etnetera.dev.web" })

public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Root config:

```
package com.etnetera.dev.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.etnetera.dev.storage" })
@PropertySource("classpath:service.config.properties")
public class SpringRootConfig {


}
```

Properties file is located in

/src/main/resources

Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
//apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

gretty {
  port = 8081
  contextPath = 'spring4'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
}

// JDK 7
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/'}
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile(
        ['org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:4.0.1.201506240215-r'],
        ['com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client:2.0.0-m2'],
        ['javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'],
        ['org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.1.RELEASE'],
        ['org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.2.1.RELEASE'],
        ['ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'])

    //include in compile only, exclude in the war
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

}

//For Eclipse IDE only
eclipse {

  wtp {
    component {

      //define context path, default to project folder name
      contextPath = 'spring4'

    }

  }
}
```

I have linked Gradle dependencies in Eclipse project and Web App Libraries which seems to be same. Both have Spring in version 4.2.1.RELEASE

There are no Spring libs in Tomcat8/lib

In Eclipse Tomcat has linked Spring libs in version 4.2.1.RELEASE (found under Tomcat 8 overview -> launch configuration -> source)

I am kinda newbie with Spring and I have tried googling solutions for few hours with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you build the war and then open it (it's a zip file) can you check that your libraries have the correct versions ? If yes you have libraries somewhere else in the classpath that conflict. To me there is no doubt that your problem comes from a conflict with the versions of your dependencies but I can't see anything wrong with your graddle file

Comment: I have resolved the issue by cleaning project, cleaning Tomcat and cleaning Tomcat Work dir. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries, sometime IDE can have weird behaviors and make us seek for phantom problems. Glad to hear that everything is working for you now !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC. Not recognizing RequestMapping annotation name attribute when loading context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405691/spring-mvc-not-recognizing-requestmapping-annotation-name-attribute-when-loadin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by cleaning project, cleaning Tomcat and cleaning Tomcat Work dir.

Anyway I had another issue with my code:

```
public class ServiceManager {

    private static volatile ServiceManager instance;

    public final JiraService jira;
    public final GitService git;
    public final JenkinsService jenkins;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConfiguration conf;

    private ServiceManager() {
        this.jira = new JiraServiceSynchronousImpl(conf);
        this.git = new JGitGitServiceImpl(conf);
        this.jenkins = new SimpleJenkinsServiceImpl(conf);
    }
```

It is wrong because Spring doesn't autowire field to use it in constructor. I fixed it with this:

```
public class ServiceManager {

    private static volatile ServiceManager instance;

    public final JiraService jira;
    public final GitService git;
    public final JenkinsService jenkins;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceManager(ServiceConfiguration conf) {
        this.jira = new JiraServiceSynchronousImpl(conf);
        this.git = new JGitGitServiceImpl(conf);
        this.jenkins = new SimpleJenkinsServiceImpl(conf);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect that you are having different versions of dependencies `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc`. Check your pom.xml and unsure you are using the very **same** version for all your spring dependencies and try again

Comment: I am using Gradle to manage my dependencies. Here is my build.gradle:

dependencies {
 
 compile(
  ['org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:4.0.1.201506240215-r'],
  ['com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client:2.0.0-m2'],
  ['javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'],
  ['org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.1.RELEASE'],
  ['org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.2.1.RELEASE'],
  ['ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'])
 
 //include in compile only, exclude in the war
 providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
 
}
...
}

Comment: Please show us your full gradle file (edit your question) + check that you don't have libs provided in your tomcat that could conflict

Comment: Gradle script added to my question

Answer (score 1):

See this part in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.path()[Ljava/lang/String;
```

Make sure you don't have multiple jar files with different versions of Spring in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I use Gradle to manage my dependencies. I have added Gradle builde script to my orginal question. As far as I can tell I have only one version of Spring linked everywhere.

Comment: use only the `org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.1.RELEASE`. `spring-webmvc` is an implementation of Spring MVC.